# how to derive and plot the FresnelS function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I am given an $g(x)= \int_{x}^{x^3} \sin(x t^2) dt$. The definition is clear `g[x]` is an integral of function `Sin` from `x` to `x^3` .I am asked to find its derivative and plot the FresnelS function over [-10,10]. 
Now when I use `D` command for `g[x]`, it gives result after evaluating the integral, which is a FresnelS function, but i know that mathematically derivative cancels out integration and gives the functions as it is. That's if I am not wrong? how can I differentiate `g[x]` ? And if the result is a FresnelS function? Because  my teacher asks in the same question to plot the FresnelS function, should I plot the result or  the given integral `g[x]`? i did try to plot both but I think my result is all wrong. I don't get it.

```
g[x_] = Hold[Integrate[Sin[x*t^2], {t, x, x^3}]]
a=ReleaseHold[%]
D[a,x]
Plot[(Sqrt[π/2] (-FresnelS[Sqrt[2/π] x^(3/2)] + 
FresnelS[Sqrt[2/π] x^(7/2)]))/Sqrt[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: _but i know that mathematically derivative cancels out integration_ - this is not true in general.

Comment: @yarchik sorry , i thought there are editors on this site for correcting grammar or rephrasing my sentences.

Comment: The result of `Integrate[Sin[x*t^2],{t,x,x^3}]` is not a single `FresnelS` function. If you want to plot `FresnelS` just do `Plot[FresnelS[t],{t,-10,10}]`. If you want to plot the derivative of `g[x]` just do `g[x_] = Integrate[Sin[x*t^2], {t, x, x^3}]` and `Plot[g'[x],{x,-10,10}]`. The quote ' after `g` indicates the derivative.

Comment: Note that as shown in the documentation, the definition for [`FresnelS`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FresnelS.html) used in Mathematica is `Integrate[Sin[Pi t^2/2], {t, 0, x}]`. Then its derivative `FresnelS'[x]` is `Sin[(Pi*x^2)/2]`

Comment: @flinty I am not really sure what my teacher wants me to plot but i am assuming its the result i get after derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
f[x_] = Integrate[Sin[t^2], {t, x, x^3}]
D[f[x], x]
h[x_] = Exp[-x]
Plot[{f[x], h[x]}, {x, -2, 2}]
FindRoot[f[x] == h[x], {x, 0}]
```

Comment: And if I needed to find x values where f[x] is equal to another function h[x]=e^-x in mathematica. Using Solve[e^-x= f[x],x] doesn't give any result. Is there any other command i can use to find values of x where the two functions intersect with?

Comment: @yarchik it's `Sin[x t^2]` not `Sin[t^2]`.

Comment: @flinty I guess, it was a mistake in the OP.

Comment: @HaneenHussam That's already a different question. The post should normally contain only one, but I have counted already 5, albeit related questions.

Comment: @yarchik Well that's when I solve it mathematically, i get 5 points It's definitely obvious when you plot them together.But using the program, I was wondering If there is a special command to find them directly for the functions above.  Or do i need to post a question about this separately?

Comment: @HaneenHussam See updated answer.